# C# control for XML edit with autocomplete based on XSD

Tags: c#, xml, autocomplete, xsd, controls

I have a C# windows form application with basically a textbox on it where I could enter XML. I also have an XSD file. Before processing (or after a key-up event) I’m able to validate the XML against the XSD. I really like the autocomplete features of visual studio. Because the XSD is know it knows exactly with options are allowd. Is there any C# control that does the same? I saw some JavaScript and WPF implementations, but no classic windows forms solutions.

Answer (score 1):

[FastColoredTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting) is a component that supports syntax highlight, and acutocomplete features similar to intellisense. I think it is the component you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, this looks really nice. But it seem to have no XSD based node name suggestions and that kind of stuff.

Comment: @LsH You have to populate the autocomplete list of suggestion once you extracted them from the xsd. I don't think you will find a component that already does all the job.